# How is my 100000 x 200 data matrix converted to an image?

Tags: r, image

I am curious to know the algorithm behind R's Image function when I ask it to make me an image of 2K X 32K px using my data matrix of 100K x 200. 
I am feeding my data matrix in to the R Image function, and it makes me a black and white image of my specified 2K X 32K px size, compression=none. When i convert the tiff image into a matrix it gives me a binary (1,0) dim=2K x 32K matrix. I am unable to map how the tiff function selects what color goes at x,y=1,1 and what goes for x,y=200,10000 coordinate on the tiff image matrix, specifically how the tiff image matrix is created, rules, etc... Any guidance is deeply appreciated.

```
library(RColorBrewer)   
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c( "white","black"))(n=2);
tiff(file="N.tiff",width=2000, height=32000, units="px", res=600);
dim(data)
[1] 180000  200
image(t(data), xaxt= "n", yaxt= "n", bty="n", col=my_palette);
library(tiff)
img <- readTIFF("N.tiff");
write.table(t(img),file='N.csv',row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,sep=',');
dim(img)
[1] 32000  2000
```

I was wondering if there is program that can compute the number of rows per strip from my TIFF image.

Comment: You should show us the code you were using, along with something to generate a matrix like your original dataset, so we can run it.

Comment: I just posted my code @user2554330. My question is more directed on the theoretical aspect of how a data matrix is transformed into a image matrix.

Comment: Why do you use 2G for 2,000? 2k is normally 2,000. 2G is normally 2,000,000,000.

Comment: @mparida, I asked for the code because it will determine how the transformation is done.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks! , I have modified my post accordingly.

Comment: @user2554330 Hope the edits help in that process. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I also looked into R documentation and it looks like image function does not use any interpolation. This brings me back to my question on how my 2K X 32K image is showing my 200 X 100K matrix.

Answer (score 1):

`image()` works by creating a small rectangle of the appropriate colour for each entry in the matrix.  Since your matrix is 200 by 180000 (after you transpose it), you'll get that many rectangles arranged in the plot region.  You asked for the overall window to be 2000px wide, 32000px high at 600 dpi, so the overall window will be 3.3in wide, 53.3in high.  It will have margins of a bit less than an inch on the left and smaller on the right side, so the plot region will take up only part of that width.

Working out the mapping from matrix entry to pixel is complicated by the margins.  Try some smaller examples on screen if you want to see what it's like.  For example, this code

```
setwd("~/temp")
data <- matrix(NA, 10000, 20)
data <- row(data) + 100*col(data)
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c( "white","black"))(n=20)

image(t(data), xaxt= "n", yaxt= "n", bty="n", col=my_palette)
```

gives this image when reshaped to be much taller than wide:

[image]

You might want to use `par(mai=c(0,0,0,0))` to make the mapping simpler by having no margins.  You've also got fewer pixels than matrix entries in the vertical direction.  I don't know if R will sample or average the colours in what it shows.

Comment: Thank you for your help @user2554330, and yes I am using the par(mar=c(0,0,0,0)) instead, I forgot to mention that. Yes that is what I am after, how the Tiff file is generated when I say few pixels than matrix rows without compression. I am reading up on TIFF compression algorithms.